# Java - how to zoom in/zoom out text in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, text, zooming

I am writing in a notepad. And I want to implement text scaling in my notepad. But I don't know how to do it. I'm trying to find it but everyone is suggesting to change the font size. But I need another solution.

I am create new project and add buttons and JTextArea.

```
package zoomtest;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class zoom {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    zoom window = new zoom();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public zoom() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JButton ZoomIn = new JButton("Zoom in");
        ZoomIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //Code here...
            }
        });
        panel.add(ZoomIn);
        
        JButton Zoomout = new JButton("Zoom out");
        Zoomout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //Code here...
            }
        });
        panel.add(Zoomout);
        
        JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
        frame.getContentPane().add(jta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want to change th size of the text without changing the font size (which is basicly the same)? Where's the problem with just changing the font size?

Comment: @Ausgefuchster, I am using the JFontChooser library. And when I change the text size, my zoom will be reset.

Comment: You have to change the font size.  You make a copy of the font with the new font size.  See the `deriveFont` method in the `updatePanels` method in my answer.

Comment: _I am using the JFontChooser library_ Google shows me that there are several libraries named `JFontChooser`. [Edit] your question and post a link to the library that you are using. Nonetheless it doesn't look like the code in your question references `JFontChooser`. Are you looking for a solution that uses that library?

Comment: _when I change the text size, my zoom will be reset_ Are you saying that your code does not do what you expect it to? Are you therefore asking for help in debugging your code? If you are then I suggest that you [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

I reworked your GUI.  Here's how it looks when the application starts.  I typed some text so you can see the font change.

[image]

Here's how it looks after we zoom out.

[image]

Here's how it looks after we zoom in.

[image]

Stack Overflow scales the images, so it's not as obvious that the text is zooming.

## Explanation

Swing was designed to be used with [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  I created two `JPanels`, one for the `JButtons` and one for the `JTextArea`.  I put the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` so you could type more than 10 lines.

I keep track of the font size in an `int` field.  This is a simple application model.  Your Swing application should always have an application model made up of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ZoomTextExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new ZoomTextExample();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private int pointSize;

    private Font textFont;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JTextArea jta;

    private JTextField pointSizeField;

    public ZoomTextExample() {
        this.pointSize = 16;
        this.textFont = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, pointSize);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(createTextAreaPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton zoomIn = new JButton("Zoom in");
        zoomIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                incrementPointSize(+2);
                updatePanels();
            }
        });
        panel.add(zoomIn);

        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Current font size:");
        panel.add(label);

        pointSizeField = new JTextField(3);
        pointSizeField.setEditable(false);
        pointSizeField.setText(Integer.toString(pointSize));
        panel.add(pointSizeField);

        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));

        JButton zoomOut = new JButton("Zoom out");
        zoomOut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                incrementPointSize(-2);
                updatePanels();
            }
        });
        panel.add(zoomOut);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createTextAreaPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        jta = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        jta.setFont(textFont);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jta);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private void updatePanels() {
        pointSizeField.setText(Integer.toString(pointSize));
        textFont = textFont.deriveFont((float) pointSize);
        jta.setFont(textFont);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private void incrementPointSize(int increment) {
        pointSize += increment;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the pictures are arranged correctly? The 20pt doesn't seem bigger than the 16pt?

Comment: @matt: As I said in my answer, Stack Overflow scales the images, so it's not as obvious that the text is zooming.

Comment: Oh right, I was thinking the text would be scaling in the window. The whole window is changing sizes.

Comment: @matt, yes, the window is resized. And it doesn't suit me very well.

Comment: @NPE: Just remove the `pack` method call from the `updatePanels` method if you don't want the window to resize.  You can take an existing Swing application and modify one line at a time to see what changes happen.  Experimenting is how you learn.